# How to calculate Eigenvector centrality of an undirected network

Tags: graph-theory, igraph, eigenvector

I am using `igraph` library in R to calculate the Eigenvector centrality of my network.

By using `evcent` function, I am getting the result of Eigenvector centrality of my network.

But how it is being mathematically calculated and as its definition says that its algorithm is iterative.

Can any body shows a method that how it is being calculated over a network mathematically?

Let's consider that the following graph is my network and the values which i am getting as the result of eigenvector centrality how these value are being computed.

```
library(igraph)
g2 <- graph.formula(A:B - A:C, X:Z - X:Y - X:B, C:Z , C:X )
ec <- evcent(g2)
ec <- ec$vector
```

Comment: I have edited your question to make it more readable, but I still don't understand what is your question.

Comment: I am not clear about how the eigenvector centrality is being calculated. So i want to know mathematical calculation of eigenvector centrality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

evcent, and equivalently eigen_centrality, compute the largest eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix and it's corresponding eigenvector.  It uses the C routine "R_igraph_eigenvector_centrality" for a more efficient computation.  For more information on the motivation behind eigenvector centrality see, for example, [Social and Economic Networks](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8767.html).  You can also compute eigenvector centrality through the built in spectral decomposition of a matrix using the eigen function in R,

```
library(igraph)
g2 <- graph.formula(A:B - A:C, X:Z - X:Y - X:B, C:Z , C:X )
ec <- evcent(g2)
ec <- ec$vector
ed <- eigen(as.matrix(get.adjacency(g2)))
ec2 <- ed$vectors[,1]
```

Note that eigen will return a normalized vector whereas evcent will not.  Therefore ec2 will be a scalar multiple of ec.

Comment: Thanks Ryan i understood the method how it is being calculated. It helped..Thank you..:)